# Building queries into Rails API requests in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am trying to begin work on building some API functionality in a Rails app and I’m just playing around with the concepts in a simple app where a `Movie has_many :reviews` and `Review belongs_to :movie` and I’d like a url that looks like `/api/movies?review=mark`.  Here is more data for context:

```
2.6.3 :005 > m
 => #<Movie id: 12, title: "Wonder Woman", rating: "PG-13", total_gross: 0.821847012e9, created_at: "2019-08-19 13:48:08", updated_at: "2019-08-19 13:48:08", description: "When a pilot crashes and tells of conflict in the ...", released_on: "2017-06-02", director: "Patty Jenkins", duration: "141 min", image_file_name: "wonder-woman.png">
2.6.3 :006 > m.reviews
  Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."movie_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["movie_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: 1, name: "mark", stars: 3, comment: "blah", movie_id: 12, created_at: "2019-08-19 13:49:44", updated_at: "2019-08-19 13:49:44">]>
```

I have a basic api build so I can do `/api/movies` and will return json with all movies, but not sure where to go from here for query functionality in the a get request. Some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: What would you want `api/movies?review=mark` to return?

Comment: @jvillan all reviews for movies that have the name "mark". Though I type that the URL seems ambiguous 

Answer (score 0):

You say you want:

> all reviews for movies that have the name "mark"

In which case, it seems like you should be calling:

```
/api/reviews?review%5Bname%5D%5B%5D=mark
```

Which will give you request something like:

```
Started GET "/api/reviews?review%5Bname%5D%5B%5D=mark" for ::1 at 2019-08-21 17:40:28 -0700
Processing by Api::ReviewsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {review: {name: ['mark']}}
```

Then, in your `Api::ReviewsController`, you could do something like:

```
class Api::ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:review]
      @reviews = Review.where(review_params)
    else
      @reviews = Review.all
    end
    ... do some stuff like rendering json
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(name: [])
  end

end
```

And that will return all reviews for movies where `Review` has a `name` value of `mark`. You could pass in multiple names and get back records for multiple reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check `queryko` gem for building API queries